# Validate DTO in Get mathod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to pass a DTO to Get method:

```
@GetMapping
public void my_get(MyDto myDto){
    
}
```

Above code work's correctly but validations on fields not worked.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDto {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = ValidateConstant.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    String id;

    String uri;

    String type;

    String version;
}
```

I'm also add `@Valid` annotation but also Get method return 200 in response.

Answer (score 0):

add `@Valid` annotation

```
public void my_get(@Valid MyDto myDto){
```

if that does not help, add `@Validated` at the class level.